# Rails 4, Devise remember token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am trying to find how [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) generates the `remember_token`.

I have noticed that it is generated (and stored in a cookie) even when there is no token column in the DB to hold it. I'd like to understand how it works, but I cannot find the right location in its source.

Could anyone point me to the source code file, please?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The value comes from the rememberable_value method in the rememberable model.

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/rememberable.rb#L75

You can see there that the *remember_token* attribute/method if the model responds to it (which is a left over from previous versions where there was an actual DB attribute) or failing that it pulls the value from the authenticatable_salt method.

The authenticatable_salt method used, if you are using the database_authenticatable module is here:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/database_authenticatable.rb#L132

That method then returns the first 29 characters of the user's encrypted password, which is then used at the remember_token.